# FosUserBundle's form with bootstrap theme

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twig, symfony-2.7

I am starting a new Symfony project and I'm using the FosUserBundle. I have my login and register page working, but I can't get my bootstrap form theme working for the login page. Note: it does work for the register form, because the form's variable is actually named form.

This is my template:

```
{% extends '@Frontend/Layout/home.html.twig' %}
{% form_theme form 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% block fos_user_content %}{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

I am overriding the original FosUserBundle's template using a child bundle. Again, this works for the register form, but not for the login form. When I go to the register page and I look at the source I find this:

```
<label class="control-label required" for="fos_user_registration_form_username">form.username</label>
```

As you can see, the label is called form.username, so the variable that holds the form is called form. I figured that's whny {% form_theme form %} worked, so I looked at the login page:

```
Variable "form" does not exist in FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig at line 2
```

This was weird to me, so I removed the form theme and looked at the login page:

```
<label for="username">security.login.username</label>
```

So, I thought: the form is called security, so let's do this:

```
{% form_theme security 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig' %}
```

But, this did not work. My question: what variable is the login form stored in? I know that I can override the form, but I think it's weird that the forms are stored in different variables, so my second question is: why are the forms stored in different variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was running in the same issue some days ago. `FOSUserBundle` isn't using the form component, so it has plain form templates. This means you can't use Form Theme here. So bad. :-(